DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE intermittently
I have a website (greatsistema.com) for internal company use that we use from several locations. Intermittently at 1-2 branches (different locations) the site goes down with a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN or a ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE error. On these machines the internet is fine because you browse other sites, but our site shows this error.
It is not a cache problem, because even if you use another browser that you have never used, the same error appears. We already released the IP, renew, flushdns, change DNS to Google's DNS, etc; I disable antivirus, firewall, clear cache and nothing changes. If I connected my device to another network (for example, sharing my cell phone internet), the site displays correctly.
The strange thing is that the next morning everything returns to normal, but 10-15 days later the problem appears again.
The current solution is to restart the internet modem and the problem is solved immediately.
What could be the cause of this problem? What to do to solve it permanently? Thank you!!!

share the dns configuration and nslookup response for these machines
